# How rotate a Landscape Image to Portrait in Android OpenCV 3

Tags: java, android, opencv3.0

This code rotate a image from Landscape to Portrait, but I can't do it in Android. What is the equivalent code?

```
import cv2
import numpy


img = cv2.imread('original.png')

h, w = img.shape[:2]

img2 = numpy.zeros((w, h, 3), numpy.uint8)
cv2.transpose(img, img2)
cv2.flip(img2, 1, img2)

cv2.imwrite('rotate.png', img2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your image as OpenCV Mat in Android (you can load an image by using the `Imgcodecs.imread()` method).

Then you can just do it like this:

```
Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("path/to/file"); // initialize this with your image from file

Core.flip(src.t(), src, 1); // this will rotate the image 90° clockwise
Core.flip(src.t(), src, 0); // this will rotate the image 90° counter-clockwise
```

After that, use `Imgcodecs.imwrite()` to save the image. Make sure you add the permissions to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Hi. I apply the code below then the image is fliped (rotate) but still in landcape just .

Comment: Core.transpose(mRgba, mRgbaT);
Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaF, mRgba.size(), 0, 0, 0);
Core.flip(mRgbaF, mRgba, 1);
;

Comment: Original --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAKso4Vz99QVHdHT21aTUROa0k        Flipped --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAKso4Vz99QNUoxN2pMbzhJdzQ

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]...

Get a landscape, like (W)800 x (H) 600, and outpout a (H)800 x (W)600.  :)

`Core.transpose(mRgba, mRgbaT);
    Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaF, mRgbaT.size(), 0, 0, 0);
    Core.flip(mRgbaF, mRgbaF, 1);`